# settings from qt project file in code

Tags: qt

Are the .pro file settings somehow accessible from within the code?

I want to use conditional compilation but I need to know whether 
testlib (or whatever)

QT += testlib

is added in the project file.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. If your application is compiled with the testlib, `QT_TESTLIB_LIB` will be defined.

So you could to this:

```
#ifdef QT_TESTLIB_LIB
// test code
#endif
```

Answer (score 4):

In addition to Kyle's answer you can also more generally make [conditional checks on configuration](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qmake-advanced-usage.html#configuration-and-scopes) and use these to set preprocessor macros with the [DEFINES variable](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qmake-variable-reference.html#defines) .